# Java QueryDsl code generation does not generate Q class

Tags: java, code-generation, querydsl

I'm making a Spring project, where i'm using QueryDsl for the entities. I'm picking up this project from a few months back, where i already had 1 generated class (QUser). Now i made a new entity called Permission, and modified the User entity. When i'm building the project, the QUser doesn't change, and the QPermission class is not generating either. What am i doing wrong? Here's the entity and pom.xml for QueryDsl.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "permission")
public class Permission {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private Long id;

   @Column(name = "name", length = 100, nullable = false)
   private String name;


   public Long getId() {
       return id;
   }

   public void setId(Long id) {
       this.id = id;
  }

    public String getName() {
       return name;
   }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

And the pom.xml:

```
[..]
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>process</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/java</outputDirectory>
                        <processor>com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
[...]
```

I was following the documentation:
http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/3.2.0/reference/html/ch03s03.html
I'm using IntellIJ IDEA and tried the "Rebuild project" option as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you show the dependencies you put in your pom.xml ?

I've made some tests starting from scratch

Here are the dependencies :

```
<dependencies>
    ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    ...
</dependencies>
```

And the plugin :

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>process</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources</outputDirectory>
                        <processor>com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

The complete source code I've tried to generate QFiles and that worked :

https://github.com/githubjul/test-so-querydsl

I don't run the project, only compile it to verify it works.

Answer (score 2):

I was having trouble getting the files generated(the Q classes), and it turned out that building my maven project using IntelliJ would not work, so I had to run this command instead in the command line to build the project:

```
./mvnw install
```

And the files were generated for me, and in order to be able to use these generated files in my source code, I had to mark the folder that contains these
files as "Generated Sources Root", so in this case navigate to this path:

```
target/generated-sources/java
```

right mouse click on **java** folder --> mark directory as --> Generated Sources Root.

After this you will be able to import these Q classes in your source code.

Comment: I could not execute mvnw. But i ran mvn install. I checked my generated sources folder and the Q files were there. Then the second part of this answer helped me resolve the errors on Intellij

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working *pom.xml*

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.hello</groupId>
    <artifactId>querydsl</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>querydsl</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <querydsl.version>4.1.0</querydsl.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
            <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.javax.persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.0-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>process</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources</outputDirectory>
                            <processor>com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

and the generated class:

```
/**
 * QPermission is a Querydsl query type for Permission
 */
@Generated("com.querydsl.codegen.EntitySerializer")
public class QPermission extends EntityPathBase<Permission> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -479242270L;

    public static final QPermission permission = new QPermission("permission");

    public final NumberPath<Long> id = createNumber("id", Long.class);

    public final StringPath name = createString("name");

    public QPermission(String variable) {
        super(Permission.class, forVariable(variable));
    }

    public QPermission(Path<? extends Permission> path) {
        super(path.getType(), path.getMetadata());
    }

    public QPermission(PathMetadata metadata) {
        super(Permission.class, metadata);
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you explain to me, how you do it? Do i just change the pom.xml contents then just build? Or is there something else? I wanna make a lot more entities, and all of them are gonna need a Q class as well.

Comment: @iron24 Can you post your pom.xml? Also, how do you trigger the build, with: mvn clean package?

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following dependency did it for me:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
    <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>3.7.4</version>
</dependency>
```

You can look up the latest version here:

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.mysema.querydsl/querydsl-jpa

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue using IntelliJ.

The following steps worked for me:

1. Right-clicked my POM,
2. Clicked 'Maven',
3. Clicked 'reload project'.

This seemed to do the trick.